# mysql create unique index with whitespace in index name

Tags: c#, mysql, indexing

When I run the query

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX User Name ON my_table (user_name)

OR

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "User Name" ON my_table (user_name)
```

mysql throws a 1064 error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Name on my_table (user_name)' at line 1
```

How can I create an index where the index name has some whitespace characters included, I already tried with quotes, it didn't work.

Some more info:  When a supervisor wants to add more users (through a config menu from my application), and there are duplicate values in some of the columns, .NET will throw an exception saying "Duplicate entry 'John' for key 'some_key'".

I want to make the key the same name as the column name so the error would say e.g. "Duplicate entry 'John' for key 'User Name'".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include whitespace you need to use backticks like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `User Name` ON my_table (user_name)
```